# What's a word for someone who always tries to improve things around them?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a word that refers to someone who puts effort into constantly leaving things better than the way he/she found them - an interpretation of 'stewardship'.

Sample sentence: "I've been so busy solving new problems for clients daily, that I haven't had the chance to better our internal processes. This really bothers the ________ in me."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with *steward*?

Comment: @Nathaniel I want to use it in a corporate context. Often the word 'steward' immediately conjures images of a butler or service staff, which is not what I intend.

Answer (score 6):

> "I've been so busy solving new problems for clients daily, that I haven't had the chance to better our internal processes. This really bothers the ***perfectionist*** in me."

or

> "I've been so busy solving new problems for clients daily, that I haven't had the chance to better our internal processes. This really bothers the ***go-getter*** in me."

This might sound a little narcissistic but if you feel confident about yourself you can call yourself as a go-getter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What I'm looking for is a word that describes someone who will never be satisfied, and constantly looks for new opportunities to improve things. Perfectionists attain a goal, and stop there. I hope this clarifies my question a little more!

Comment: Perfectionists don't stop after attaining their goals. In an ideal world, they might. But this world is far from ideal. Thus, nothing is perfect. There's always scope for improvement and perfecting things. And that's what I assume you mean when you say "always tries to improve things". Nonetheless, I have added another straight forward word. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure a *perfectionist* ever actually feels they have achieved the status they seek, karish10 ... a *perfectionist* is what one might call an *optimistic malcontent*, so +1 for *perfectionist*, BiscuitBoy.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, ***fine-tuner***.

> fine-tune: to make small changes to (something) in order to improve the way it works or to make it exactly right [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fine%E2%80%93tune)

Answer (score 0):

You can try "improver".

> This really bothers the *improver* in me.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/improver
http://www.yourdictionary.com/improver